# GL library compilation question OS X

Tags: macos

Does anyone know how to get the GL library headers for OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)?  E.g. I'm getting this error with a sudo port install:

configure: error: You don't seem to have the GL library headers installed.

TIA,
Craig

Comment: What port are you trying to install? Are there header files in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/ ?

Comment: I'm trying to configure the pcb module in the open source electronic circuit design system gEDA.  You both are absolutely right: it's there, it's just that configure can't find it.  I need to figure out how to get gEDA's configure to see it.  Thanks!

Comment: When the configure script fails, config.log shows what the script was trying to do and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the developer tools from the OSX install DVD (xcode, etc), they should have already been installed. If you didn't, you can download a disk image from apple's site of the developer tools installer, then mount it and run the installer to get the GL headers.